# Cannot get httdocs domain working after installing XAMPP on Windows XP

Tags: xampp

Installed XAMPP correctly but when I point to  it says object not found! Why is the htdocs domain not registered correctly and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The htdocs is by default the root directory of your installation, it is not a domain.
Put all your folders and files under this folder to make them visible to Apache.

To access the local server, you need to open the browser to http://localhost/. (the domain is localhost)